# Running source command on parent shell from bash script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script where I make a few changes to the .bashrc. I then want to run the bashrc from my script so I've been running

source ~/.bashrc

to avoid having to reload my shell. The problem I've been seeing is that it's only being set in the subshell bash is running in.

Can I do anything from my script so that the source command is run in the parent shell?

Comment: Source it explicitly in the parent shell.

Answer (score 0):

What you **could** do, if you really wanted to: Provide a shell function which checks whether .bashrc has been modified, and if it is the case, sources this file. Let#s call this function `check_reload`. Then define your `PS1` as

```
PS1='$(check_reload) .....'
```

With this setup, your .bashrc will be reloaded before you get a new command line.

While this should solve your problem, I personally would not do it: I consider the information in `.bashrc` fairly static, and I would not use a script to modify it, but do it manually with a text editor. But of course everyone can do this as he likes....

Answer (score 0):

Probably a very late answer, but if you don't mind executing the content of your script in the current shell (i.e. not start a subshell), you could do:

```bash
source myScript.sh
```

The `source ~/.bashrc` you call in turn in `myScript.sh` would affect your current shell.